# "ng test" works but "node .\node_modules\jest\bin\jest.js --config=jest.conf.js" does not

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, jestjs, angular-cli

I try to get Jest debugging in Visual Studio Code running. However it seems to have problems with unrecognized imports (ES modules).

The resulting error message is:

```
FAIL  src/main/webapp/app/shared/review/review-history/review-history.component.spec.ts
 ● Test suite failed to run

Must use import to load ES Module: C:\Users\Micha\git\gitsearch\node_modules\@angular\common\fesm2020\http.mjs

> 1 | import { HttpHeaders, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
    | ^
  2 | import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
  3 | import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
  4 | import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
```

Invoking:

```
ng test
```

works like a charm, but:

```
node .\node_modules\jest\bin\jest.js --config=jest.conf.js
```

(which is equivalent to the debug statement in Visual Studio Code) results in error messages as above.

I was not able to figure out where the difference in configuration shows up between both commands.

I have already tried:

- adding "--experimental-vm-modules" to node command
- fiddling around with `transformIgnorePatterns: ['(node_modules/(?!.*\\.mjs$|dayjs/esm))']`
- and various other hints found through Google

I was not able to find out what the precise config difference between

- `ng test`  and
- `node .\node_modules\jest\bin\jest.js --config=jest.conf.js`
  is.

My config is

- Node: v20.10.0
- @angular-builders/jest@13.0.4
- ts-jest@27.1.5
- jest-preset-angular@11.1.2
- jest@29.7.0

Finally here my package.json

```
{
  "name": "gitsearch",
  "version": "1.6.0-SNAPSHOT",
  "private": true,
  "description": "Description for gitsearch",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "app:start": "./mvnw",
    "backend:build-cache": "./mvnw dependency:go-offline",
    "backend:debug": "./mvnw -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments=\"-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:8000\"",
    "backend:doc:test": "./mvnw -ntp javadoc:javadoc --batch-mode",
    "backend:info": "./mvnw -ntp enforcer:display-info --batch-mode",
    "backend:nohttp:test": "./mvnw -ntp checkstyle:check --batch-mode",
    "backend:start": "./mvnw -Dskip.installnodenpm -Dskip.npm",
    "backend:unit:test": "./mvnw -ntp -Dskip.installnodenpm -Dskip.npm verify --batch-mode -Dlogging.level.ROOT=OFF -Dlogging.level.org.zalando=OFF -Dlogging.level.tech.jhipster=OFF -Dlogging.level.at.ac.uibk.gitsearch=OFF -Dlogging.level.org.springframework=OFF -Dlogging.level.org.springframework.web=OFF -Dlogging.level.org.springframework.security=OFF",
    "build": "npm run webapp:prod --",
    "build-watch": "concurrently 'npm run webapp:build:dev -- --watch' npm:backend:start",
    "ci:backend:test": "npm run backend:info && npm run backend:doc:test && npm run backend:nohttp:test && npm run backend:unit:test -- -P$npm_package_config_default_environment",
    "ci:e2e:package": "npm run java:$npm_package_config_packaging:$npm_package_config_default_environment -- -Pe2e -Denforcer.skip=true",
    "ci:e2e:prepare": "npm run ci:e2e:prepare:docker",
    "ci:e2e:prepare:docker": "npm run docker:db:up && npm run docker:others:up && docker ps -a",
    "ci:e2e:run": "concurrently -k -s first \"npm run ci:e2e:server:start\" \"npm run e2e:headless\"",
    "preci:e2e:server:start": "npm run docker:db:await --if-present && npm run docker:others:await --if-present",
    "ci:e2e:server:start": "java -jar target/e2e.$npm_package_config_packaging --spring.profiles.active=$npm_package_config_default_environment -Dlogging.level.ROOT=OFF -Dlogging.level.org.zalando=OFF -Dlogging.level.tech.jhipster=OFF -Dlogging.level.at.ac.uibk.gitsearch=OFF -Dlogging.level.org.springframework=OFF -Dlogging.level.org.springframework.web=OFF -Dlogging.level.org.springframework.security=OFF --logging.level.org.springframework.web=ERROR",
    "ci:e2e:teardown": "npm run ci:e2e:teardown:docker",
    "ci:e2e:teardown:docker": "npm run docker:db:down --if-present && npm run docker:others:down && docker ps -a",
    "ci:frontend:build": "npm run webapp:build:$npm_package_config_default_environment",
    "ci:frontend:test": "npm run ci:frontend:build && npm test",
    "ci:server:await": "echo \"Waiting for server at port $npm_package_config_backend_port to start\" && wait-on http-get://localhost:$npm_package_config_backend_port/management/health && echo \"Server at port $npm_package_config_backend_port started\"",
    "clean-www": "rimraf target/classes/static/app/{src,target/}",
    "cleanup": "rimraf target/classes/static/",
    "docker:app:up": "docker-compose -f src/main/docker/app.yml up -d",
    "docker:db:down": "docker-compose -f src/main/docker/mysql.yml down -v --remove-orphans",
    "docker:db:up": "docker-compose -f src/main/docker/mysql.yml up -d",
    "docker:elasticsearch:down": "docker-compose -f src/main/docker/elasticsearch.yml down -v --remove-orphans",
    "docker:elasticsearch:up": "docker-compose -f src/main/docker/elasticsearch.yml up -d",
    "docker:others:await": "echo \"Waiting for Elasticsearch to start\" && wait-on \"http-get://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?wait_for_status=green&timeout=60s\" && echo \"Elasticsearch started\"",
    "docker:others:down": "npm run docker:elasticsearch:down",
    "predocker:others:up": "",
    "docker:others:up": "npm run docker:elasticsearch:up",
    "e2e": "export E2E_PASSWORD=search@admin; protractor --baseUrl='http://localhost:8080/'  src/test/javascript/protractor.conf.js --disableChecks",
    "e2e:ci": "export JHI_E2E_HEADLESS=true; export E2E_PASSWORD=$E2E_PASSWORD ; protractor --baseUrl='https://dev-exchange.codeability-austria.uibk.ac.at/' src/test/javascript/protractor.conf.js --disableChecks",
    "e2e:dev": "concurrently -k -s first \"./mvnw\" \"npm run e2e\"",
    "e2e:devserver": "concurrently -k -s first \"npm run backend:start\" \"npm start\" \"wait-on http-get://localhost:9000 && npm run e2e:headless -- -c baseUrl=http://localhost:9000\"",
    "pree2e:headless": "npm run ci:server:await",
    "e2e:headless": "npm run e2e:protractor:headless --",
    "e2e:protractor": "protractor src/test/javascript/protractor.conf.js",
    "e2e:protractor:headless": "npm run e2e:protractor --",
    "e2e:update-webdriver": "webdriver-manager update --gecko false",
    "java:docker": "./mvnw -ntp verify -DskipTests -Pprod jib:dockerBuild",
    "java:docker:arm64": "npm run java:docker -- -Djib-maven-plugin.architecture=arm64",
    "java:docker:dev": "npm run java:docker -- -Pdev,webapp",
    "java:docker:prod": "npm run java:docker -- -Pprod",
    "java:jar": "./mvnw -ntp verify -DskipTests --batch-mode",
    "java:jar:dev": "npm run java:jar -- -Pdev,webapp",
    "java:jar:prod": "npm run java:jar -- -Pprod",
    "java:war": "./mvnw -ntp verify -DskipTests --batch-mode -Pwar",
    "java:war:dev": "npm run java:war -- -Pdev,webapp",
    "java:war:prod": "npm run java:war -- -Pprod",
    "jest": "jest --coverage --logHeapUsage --maxWorkers=2 --config jest.conf.js",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.ts",
    "lint:fix": "npm run lint -- --fix",
    "prepare": "husky install",
    "prettier:check": "prettier --check \"{,src/main/java/**/,src/test/java/**/,src/main/webapp/**/}*.{md,json,yml,html,ts,css,scss,java}\"",
    "prettier:format": "prettier --write \"{,src/main/java/**/,src/test/java/**/,src/main/webapp/**/}*.{md,json,yml,html,ts,css,scss,java}\"",
    "protractor": "protractor src/test/javascript/protractor.conf.js ",
    "serve": "npm run start --",
    "start": "npm install && ng build --configuration development && ng serve --hmr",
    "start-tls": "npm run webapp:dev-ssl",
    "test": "ng test --coverage --log-heap-usage -w=2",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch",
    "watch": "concurrently npm:start npm:backend:start",
    "webapp:build": "npm run clean-www && npm run webapp:build:dev",
    "webapp:build:dev": "ng build --configuration development",
    "webapp:build:prod": "ng build --configuration production",
    "webapp:dev": "ng serve",
    "webapp:dev-ssl": "ng serve --ssl",
    "webapp:dev-verbose": "ng serve --verbose",
    "webapp:prod": "npm run clean-www && npm run webapp:build:prod",
    "webapp:test": "npm run test --"
  },
  "config": {
    "backend_port": "8080",
    "default_environment": "prod",
    "packaging": "jar"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "13.4.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.3.9",
    "@angular/common": "13.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "13.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "^13.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "13.4.0",
    "@angular/localize": "13.4.0",
    "@angular/material": "^13.3.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "13.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "13.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "13.4.0",
    "@elastic/elasticsearch": "^8.9.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.10.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-common-types": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "11.0.0",
    "@ngqp/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "14.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "7.0.0",
    "ajv": "^8.12.0",
    "angular-tag-cloud-module": "^13.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.6.2",
    "colorjs.io": "^0.4.5",
    "dayjs": "1.11.9",
    "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^13.1.2",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "10.0.1",
    "ngx-markdown": "^13.1.0",
    "ngx-webstorage": "9.0.0",
    "npm": "^10.2.5",
    "npm-check-updates": "^16.10.17",
    "rxjs": "7.8.1",
    "swagger-ui-dist": "4.2.1",
    "tslib": "2.6.1",
    "yarn": "^1.22.21",
    "zone.js": "^0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "13.1.0",
    "@angular-builders/jest": "13.0.4",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "13.3.11",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "13.5.0",
    "@angular/cli": "13.3.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "13.4.0",
    "@angular/service-worker": "13.4.0",
    "@types/chai": "4.3.5",
    "@types/chai-string": "1.4.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.11",
    "@types/jspdf": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.196",
    "@types/mocha": "8.2.0",
    "@types/node": "16.11.21",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "4.1.15",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.10.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.10.0",
    "browser-sync": "^2.29.3",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "2.3.0",
    "chai": "4.3.7",
    "chai-as-promised": "7.1.1",
    "chai-string": "1.5.0",
    "concurrently": "7.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "10.2.1",
    "eslint": "8.46.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.10.0",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "3.1.1",
    "folder-hash": "4.0.4",
    "generator-jhipster": "^8.1.0",
    "husky": "^7.0.4",
    "jest-date-mock": "1.0.8",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-junit": "13.0.0",
    "jest-preset-angular": "13.1.4",
    "jest-sonar-reporter": "2.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "12.2.2",
    "merge-jsons-webpack-plugin": "2.0.1",
    "mocha": "^10.2.0",
    "prettier": "^2.5.1",
    "prettier-plugin-java": "1.6.1",
    "prettier-plugin-packagejson": "2.4.5",
    "protractor": "7.0.0",
    "rimraf": "3.0.2",
    "ts-jest": "29.1.1",
    "ts-node": "9.1.1",
    "typescript": "4.6.4",
    "wait-on": "6.0.0",
    "webdriver-manager": "12.1.9",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "4.9.0",
    "webpack-merge": "5.9.0",
    "webpack-notifier": "1.15.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16.13.1"
  },
  "cacheDirectories": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "jestSonar": {
    "reportPath": "target/test-results/jest",
    "reportFile": "TESTS-results-sonar.xml"
  }
}
```

my jest.conf.js

```
const { pathsToModuleNameMapper } = require('ts-jest');

const {
  compilerOptions: { paths = {}, baseUrl = './' },
} = require('./tsconfig.json');
const environment = require('./webpack/environment');

module.exports = {
  verbose: true,  
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['(node_modules/(?!.*\\.mjs$|dayjs/esm))'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.spec.ts?$': [
      'ts-jest',
      {
        //the content you'd placed at "global"
        babel: true,
        tsconfig: 'tsconfig.spec.json',
        useESM: true,
      },
    ],
  },
  resolver: 'jest-preset-angular/build/resolvers/ng-jest-resolver.js',
  globals: {
    ...environment,
  },
  roots: ['<rootDir>', `<rootDir>/${baseUrl}`],
  modulePaths: [`<rootDir>/${baseUrl}`],
  setupFiles: ['jest-date-mock'],
  cacheDirectory: '<rootDir>/target/jest-cache',
  coverageDirectory: '<rootDir>/target/test-results/',
  moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(paths, { prefix: `<rootDir>/${baseUrl}/` }),
  reporters: ['default', ['jest-junit', { outputDirectory: '<rootDir>/target/test-results/', outputName: 'TESTS-results-jest.xml' }]],
  testResultsProcessor: 'jest-sonar-reporter',
  testMatch: ['<rootDir>/src/main/webapp/app/**/@(*.)@(spec.ts)'],
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  testEnvironmentOptions: {
    url: 'http://localhost/',
    html: '<html lang="de></html>',
  },
};
```

my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src/main/webapp/",
    "outDir": "./target/classes/static/",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true,
    "preserveWhitespaces": true,
    "types": ["node"]
  }
}
```

and my angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "gitsearch": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src/main/webapp",
      "prefix": "jhi",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./webpack/webpack.custom.js"
            },
            "outputPath": "target/classes/static/",
            "index": "src/main/webapp/index.html",
            "main": "src/main/webapp/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/main/webapp/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/main/webapp/content",
              "src/main/webapp/favicon.ico",
              "src/main/webapp/manifest.webapp",
              "src/main/webapp/robots.txt",
              {
                "glob": "*.{js,css,html,png}",
                "input": "./node_modules/swagger-ui-dist",
                "output": "swagger-ui",
                "ignore": ["**/index.html"]
              },
              { "glob": "axios.min.js", "input": "./node_modules/axios/dist", "output": "swagger-ui" },
              { "glob": "**/*", "input": "src/main/webapp/swagger-ui/", "output": "swagger-ui" }
            ],
            "styles": ["src/main/webapp/content/scss/vendor.scss", "src/main/webapp/content/scss/global.scss"]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "serviceWorker": true,
              "ngswConfigPath": "ngsw-config.json",
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "gitsearch:build:development",
            "port": 4200
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "gitsearch:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "gitsearch:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/jest:run",
          "options": {
            "configPath": "jest.conf.js"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "gitsearch",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false,
    "cache": {
      "enabled": true,
      "path": "./target/angular-cli-cache",
      "environment": "all"
    },
    "packageManager": "npm"
  }
}
```